# How to get latest order comment on the order grid column?

Tags: magento-1.9

In `magento 1.9` how we can get comment column in `sale -> orders` with the latest comment e.g `Customer is redirected to Paypal`
Any idea what will be the query for this?

Answer (score 7):

Create your custom renderer, extended from renderer abstract:

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_History extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $orderId = $row->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $history = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
        return $history->getComment();
    }
}
```

Then add new column to order grid, with this renderer:

```
$this->addColumn('history', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('History status'),
    'type'  => 'text',
    'renderer' => new Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_History()
));
```

Comment: Hi, @zhartaunik  I need the same for Magento 2 Is that possible ?

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/39050 Thanks @zhartaunik

Comment: Hi, Is it also possible to filter on this renderer? how would i need to implement this?