# Grid with data from other table

Tags: database, adminhtml, grid, magento-community

How to get field value in adminhtml grid based on other table? For example I have in table id of record from another table which have field "name" and need to show field "name" instead of id.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62856/how-to-get-latest-order-comment-on-the-order-grid-column/62859#62859 if you have any questions - ask them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to override the `_prepareCollection()` method in your `Grid.php` file to add desired join conditions to entity collection.

Depending on entity type (EAV or Flat) you can use different join methods.

I suggest you to take inspiration from Magento itself; here are some files where you can look at to find some examples:

- /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
- /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
- /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php

After joining new fields remember also you have to add related columns by overriding the `_prepareColumns()` method.

Hope it helps.